# C++ Valgrind memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator, valgrind

Valgrind tells me this:

```
==19305== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 19 of 179
==19305==    at 0x402842F: operator new(unsigned int)
==19305==    by 0x805273E: Loader::createLevel(int, int, std::string, Player*, int, int, int) 
==19305==    by 0x80551B0: Loader::loadLevel()
==19305==    by 0x80676C2: main (main.cpp:38)
```

My function `Loader:.createLevel` has got several `new` statements. How can I know which one of them is causing the leak (i.e., the line)?

Thanks!

P.S.: I'd gladly post the code but it is too long :/

Comment: The easy, long-term solution is to change arrays made with `new` to vectors and any other pointer allocated memory with `new` to smart pointers. The memory will be deallocated automatically.

Comment: @chris, I didn't create any array

Comment: Make sure you have a destructor where all the instances created at constructor on the heap is deallocated and freed at the end.

Comment: Just smart pointers then, but keep `std::vector` in mind for the future. It's superior to `new`ed arrays in every way. C++11 offers `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, which will get you by pretty well. You won't need `std::weak_ptr` nearly as often. For C++03, there's still good old `auto_ptr` that became deprecated in the context of the aforementioned three.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `-g` option to `gcc` or `g++` so that your executable have debug symbol in them. Here is example from running valgrind on binary with -g.

```
==20538== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==20538==    at 0x4A05809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:149)
==20538==    by 0x4004F7: main (test.c:8)
==20538==
==20538== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20538==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks.
==20538==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==20538==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==20538==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==20538== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==20538== To see them, rerun with: --show-reachable=yes

gcc -g test.c
```

This way you can see the line at which the allocation was made.

Comment: @l19 Was the source file for `Loader` class compiled and linked in the same build? That's strange. Can you create a simple program (that always leaks memory) and see if valgrind can report the exact line# for this, in your environment?